# Render a basic div element Backbone View

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I am building a Backbone view that is simply a `<div>` and an `id` attribute.

I've commented where I'm lost with it:

```
window.ContainerView = Backbone.View.extend( {

  el: $( '<div>', { id: 'content' } ),

  initialize: function() {
    this.render();
  },

  render: function() {
    // How do I render this view?
  }
} );
```

In my `main.js`, I simply do:

```
var containerView = new ContainerView();
```

And for good measure, here is my `index.html` body section, where I include all my Backbone files.

```
<body>

  <!-- Libraries -->
  <script src="./lib/jquery-min.js"></script>
  <script src="./lib/underscore-min.js"></script>
  <script src="./lib/backbone-min.js"></script>

  <!-- Models -->

  <!-- Views -->
  <script src="./js/views/ContainerView.js"></script>

  <!-- App -->
  <script src="./js/main.js"></script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the default tag of el in Backbone is div and you can set the id is id attribute. go through the [documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#View-el)

```
window.ContainerView = Backbone.View.extend( {

  'id' : 'content',

  initialize: function() {
    this.render();
  },

  render: function() {
    $('body').append(this.el);
  }
} );
```

Comment: This is it. Thank you. 
Might use: `this.$el.appendTo($('body');` instead.

Comment: @DannyDelott the perform same task but only the syntax that changes , hope it hepls :)